# How can I write vb for macros to define a file name with a dynamic date in the title?

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to write a simple sub routine to refresh an entire workbook - I have the basic outline of the command:

```
Sub Workbook_RefreshAll()

    Workbooks("Sample.xls").RefreshAll

End Sub
```

However, this will need to run against a new file every day and the name of the file changes daily...so the file name today would be "FileName_20200820", but tomorrow it will be "FileName_20200821"...how can I write the above VB to ensure it's refreshing each day's file when the macros runs?

Comment: Where are you storing this macro?

Comment: You could store them all the the same directory and then just loop through each workbook found in the directory.

Comment: `Workbooks("Filename_" & Format(Date, "yyyymmdd") & ".xls").RefreshAll`

Comment: The macro is being stored in a template file which is used to produce the files labeled as FileName_YYYYMMDD.  We only need to refresh the files from the current day, and actually, I was mistaken - the file name for the current day is actually yesterday's date, so today's file is titled "Name_20200819".  So I'll need the refresh routine to specify the previous business days' date...

Comment: Is it necessary to update each copy of the file, or simply update the template, before you save it accordingly?

Comment: Unfortunately yes.  I work in a financial institution and the data is different every day

Answer (score 0):

Save this as a module, then you can import the module into whatever workbook you need to refresh. If you're trying to cycle through all the files in a directory this will not work, this is meant for a single Workbook.

```
Sub RefreshAll()

    Thisworkbook.RefreshAll

End Sub
```

If you have pivot tables and queries that need to be refreshed separately, you can use this:

```
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim objList As ListObject
Dim ws As Worksheet

For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    For Each objList In ws.ListObjects
        If objList.SourceType = 3 Then
            With objList.QueryTable
                .BackgroundQuery = False
                .Refresh
            End With
        End If
    Next objList
Next ws
 
Call UpdateAllPivots

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Sub

Sub UpdateAllPivots()
Dim pt As PivotTable
Dim ws As Worksheet

    For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        For Each pt In ws.PivotTables
            pt.RefreshTable
        Next pt
    Next ws
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you, much appreciated!

Comment: Did this sufficiently answer your question?